# Is it normal that when I log in and enter the page for login and refresh the page the session ID changes and a new session is created?

Tags: java, session, servlets, session-cookies

Is it normal that when I log in and enter the page for login and refresh the page the session ID changes and a new session is created?
I state that I use TomCat.
From the page of index.html through a form I log in to redirect myself to this java page, once the java html page is opened it just gives me back what I ask, but if I resfresh the page on tomcat I know that it creates me a new session, is it normal? My goal is to have a session for each individual user, how do I do it?

```
"index.html"
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Inserisci nome </title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p> <h2>Inserisci il tuo nome </h2>
    <form action="/Esercizio8/SerSal" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="nome"> <strong>USERNAME</strong> <br>
      <input type="password" name="pwd"> <strong>PASSWORD</strong> <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Invia">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

"SerSal.java"
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class SerSal extends HttpServlet{
  int count;
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException{
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("Name",name);
    session.setAttribute("Password",pwd);
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head><title>HELLO!</title></head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("Hello " + name);
    out.println("This " + (session.isNew()? "is" : "is not") + " a new session! <br>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
    out.close();
  }
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException{
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Spring Security?

Comment: if you refresh the page you are going to hit the GET method of the login servlet. Please post the doGET

Comment: in the doGet:
// Do not create a session (false) if one does not exist.
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
@JonathanLaliberte

Comment: @AndreaGhezzi i would need to see more code, edit your answer and include it

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte Done! I modified the code by inserting the .html file and the doGet method.